# Reward for saying Asher Yatzar

Tags: blessing, reward-punishment, bathroom

Is saying Asher Yatzar, the blessing after using the bathroom, something that one will get rewarded for? Will one get rewarded for each time he said Asher Yatzar?

Please cite sources.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking: do you mean "like other Brochos" or "unlike other Brochos", "is a Brocho a Mitzvah", "do we get rewarded for Mitzvos at all" or else. Please clarify.

Comment: I've seen something written abourt a "special" reward for saying this bracha diligently. I have to locate it. I think one of the rewards is "regularity". (Trust me, it's no fun being "irregular".)